# Set a provide after Future returns results

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm trying to modify data using a provider after a Future returns with data.

```
class FirstPart extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getAll(),
      initialData: Text('Loading Bro'),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError)
          return Text('error here bro');
        else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final toDoListManager = Provider.of<ListManager>(context);
          toDoListManager.list = snapshot.data;

          return Text('loaded');
        }

        return Text('load');
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<void> getAll() async {... API Request}
```

I get an error when I set the value of the provider. (I removed a lot of the error because it was too long for Stack Overflow.)

How can I modify a provider after a Future has results?

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<void>(dirty, dependencies:
flutter: [InheritedProvider<ListManager>], state: _FutureBuilderState<void>#fe02e):
flutter: type 'Text' is not a subtype of type 'List<ListItem>'
flutter:
flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
flutter:
flutter: User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was:
flutter:   FirstPart 
package:crud_todo/home.dart:16
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      FirstPart.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:crud_todo/home.dart:32
flutter: #1      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange things going on there:

- Your toDoListManager is a ListManager, toDoListManager.list returns a List and you are trying to assing a Text to thise list item since snapshot.data returns a Text Widget as initialData `toDoListManager.list = snapshot.data;`
- Another strange thing is that your getAll returns a future of void when in my opinion should return a future of List

Comment: Thank yo for the pointers, and I do appreciate it, but do you have an answer to this question?

Comment: Did you already implemented the class that extends ChangeNotifier? You will need that to make the changes and notify the widgets